# Array parameter in CFQL / stored procedure method

Tags: sql-server, codefluent

Is it possible to pass an array of parameter to a stored procedure generated through CFQL?

We generated method from designer without any problem. But I haven't found any way to unit execute it on SQL Server.

When trying to execute through code, the code would fail with given error:

> Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int

on the generated line:

```
System.Data.IDataReader reader = CodeFluentContext.Get(XYZ.Constants.XYZCodeFluentStoreName).Persistence.ExecuteReader();
```

CFQL Body is as follow:

```
LOAD (enumABCGroup[] groups) WHERE ABC.Group IN (@groups) ORDER BY NumberExt
```

Generated procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [XYZ].[ABC_LoadByGroups]
(
   @groups [int],
   @_orderBy0 [nvarchar] (64) = NULL,
   @_orderByDirection0 [bit] = 0
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT DISTINCT ... 
    FROM [XYZ].[ABC]
    WHERE [XYZ].[ABC].[ABC_Group] IN (@groups)
    ORDER BY [XYZ].[ABC].[ABC_Group] ASC, [XYZ].[ABC].[ABC_Label] ASC

    RETURN
GO
```

Underlying database system is SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.5058.0).

Thanks for your help;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to configure the SQL Server producer to target at least SQL Server 2008:

[image]

or in XML:

```
<cf:producer name="SQL Server" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
  <cf:configuration targetVersion="Sql2008" />
</cf:producer>
```

Here's some useful resources about CodeFluent Entities and TVP:

- http://blog.codefluententities.com/2015/02/11/table-valued-parameters-basics/
- http://blog.codefluententities.com/2015/07/10/table-valued-parameters-cfql-operators-2/
- http://blog.codefluententities.com/2015/07/24/table-valued-parameters-multi-columns/
- http://blog.codefluententities.com/2015/07/31/table-valued-parameters-reuse-model-collection-types/

Comment: Indeed, this parameter was missing, thanks for your support.